# IndexOutOfBoundsException when adding items to arraylist from sharedpreferences

Tags: android, exception, arraylist, sharedpreferences, indexoutofboundsexception

I got a little issue with my arraylist and I need a workaround to avoid the IndexOutOfBoundsException exception.

Here is how I'm adding the items:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : getAll().entrySet()){ // this is a map with all my sharedprefs
        list.add((Integer) entry.getValue(), myItem);
    }
```

My sharedprefs are stored in the following way:

```
<int name="test0" value="0" />
<int name="test1" value="1" />
<int name="test2" value="2" />
```

So I need to add the items to my arraylist based on the int value.
The issue comes since SharedPrefereces map store the value in a random way, so when it runs

```
list.add((Integer) entry.getValue(), myItem);
```

it throws the exception since it need to start from 0.

Anyone have a solution? Thanks

Comment: Where you define `list`.

Comment: it's a simple ArrayList<String>. It doesn't throw an npe!

Comment: try to do `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Why aren't you just using `SharedPreference`? This "workaround" seems unnecessarily complex when there is a perfectly good class to do what you're trying to do already.

Comment: MAP entry will get values in natural order.. Alphabetical order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "workaround" to this problem would be to just prepopulate your list with all 0's or some other value before you start adding to a specific position. For example:

```
int mapSize = mPrefMap.size(); 
for(int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++){
    listOfStuff.add(0);
}
```

Adding a number of 0 equal to the size of your preferences map will essentially initialize all positions at those locations to 0. You can then go back and add specific values the way you are doing.

I'm still confused why you're not just using the standard `SharedPreference` class. That would avoid the need for this workaround and save you the wasted time of having to set default values for an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you can not access an `index` that does not exists in `ArrayList` yet, and since `Map` are not ordered you are probably trying to insert at index `1` before have a valid element index `0` or at index `2` to before having a valid index `0` and `1`.

Edit:

Instead of creating an empty ArrayList you could use

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(getAll().entrySet());
```

and then using your loop

Comment: this is exactly the problem, it's trying to add the "1", before "0"